# Multiple Queries as Source Then Insert Into Excel file but in Different Sheets

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-data-factory, etl

I have this case where we have different queries we want to run in SQL Server then save it in an Excel file. I parameterized the Excel dataset I have then assigned it in the "Sheet name" property but I noticed when using Copy Data Activity the Sink property is not showing any datasets with Excel only CSV Datasets.

I've been looking for work around on this but I'm only seeing parts in the net that reads the Excel file with multiple sheets then iterate those with For Each. But what I need is vice versa. I want to write into a single Excel file the different results of my 3 queries in each different sheets using ADF.

Example:

```
FileName: Results.xlsx

SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Insert in `Results.xlsv` in sheet named `Result1`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Insert in `Results.xlsv` in sheet named `Result2`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table3
```

Insert in `Results.xlsv` in sheet named `Result3`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ADF doesn't support Excel file as a sink till now.
For your above use case, you would have to write your own custom logic in Azure functions, Databricks or Azure batch etc.

Comment: I'll look into Azure Functions. If you have some link of recommendations that would be a huge help. Thank you Nandan.

Answer (score 0):

As called out by Nandan , Excel is currently not supported as sink in ADF . I see that you have added to sql server tag and so I am assuming that you are using on-premise server , if thats the case you can use a simple powershell script . I have shared a fairly but working powershell script .below

```
#Install-Module -Name ImportExcel

$WSName =  @("result1","result2")
$Queries =  @("SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery","SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery")
foreach ($ws in $WSName)
{
$QueryOp= Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Queries[$WSName.IndexOf($ws)] -ServerInstance "Your ServerName"
$QueryOp.TimeOfQuery|Export-Excel "C:\temp\Queryresult.xlsx" -Append -WorksheetName $ws
}
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, yes we are using Azure SQL MI and thank you but I'm not sure how to integrate this to a pipeline? Is there an activity where I can call or execute a powershell script? Another question is that can I replace the value of $Queries variable to call a stored procedure like this "EXEC usp_Load_Data"?